# как остановить CountDownTimer при нажатии клавиши ввод на клавиатуре

Tags: java, android, область-видимости

Есть таймер (прописан в OnCreate):

```
 CountDownTimer timer;
    timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         text_d1.setText("Осталось: "+ millisUntilFinished / 1000);

       public void onFinish() {
         text_d1.setText("Время вышло");      
       }
   }.start();
```

Есть метод обработки нажатия клавиши ввод на виртуальной клавиатуре:

```
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                   // тут разные условия, в зависимости от того, в каком edittext нажата клавиша ввод

                  return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

Логика такая:

Как только открывается активити, таймер запускается.

Таймер автоматически останавливается через 10 сек.

Как добавить условие, что таймер также останавливается, если клавиша ввод на клавиатуре нажата?

Comment: `timer.cancel()` в методе обработки нажатия клавиши enter ?

Comment: Да, это пробовала, но как верно заметил ЮрийСПб, переменную нужно было на уровне класса объявлять. Но все равно спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам надо просто вызвать `timer.cancel()` в нужном месте. Но для этого вам надо иметь доступ к переменной `timer`. А доступ к ней в обработчиках разных можно получить, если она будет объявлена не внутри метода `onCreate`, а на уровне активити. Т.е., примерно, так:

```
CountDownTimer timer;

public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Юрий, помогло. У меня еще мало опыта (всего-то не больше месяца), и ведь чувствовала, что дело в том, что переменную объявила в onCreate))). Вопрос немного изменила, если несложно, помогите с решением. В интернете решения не нашла.

Comment: @VolhaGomel, если мой ответ решил проблему изначальную, то за него следует проголосовать и отметить верным, нажав на галочку слева от ответа. При возникновении нового вопроса нужно задавать новый вопрос, а не изменять текущий.

Comment: @VolhaGomel, задав новый вопрос вы можете откатить изменения в этом нажав на ссылку по вопросом [изменен 6 мин. назад](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/487030/revisions) и нажав `откат` на старой версии.